# Should Thunderbird send inline png attachments as text/plain?

Tags: email, thunderbird, apple-mail, attachments, mime-types

I'm composing emails in Thunderbird. When I attach png images by dragging to the header region, they are attached as

```
Content-Type: image/png;
 name="foo.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="foo.png"
```

When I attach them inline by dragging into the body, they are attached as

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.00030206.09040704@my.sending.domain.com>
```

The latter displays fine for the recipient if they are using Thunderbird, or via the gmail web interface. However, I've had complaints from OSX Mail.app users that they can only see a text file `<Mail Attachment.txt>` full of nonsense. They have to save the file and rename it to `*.png`.

Also kmail is confused by this attachment, although it seems to get some information from the attachment:
[image]

Should the attachments not be sent as `text/plain`? (However, it's interesting that Gmail understands it.) If so, then how can I make Thunderbird send inline attachments as the proper mime type?

Comment: Weird.  I am using TB 24 on Windows and inline attachments are `image/jpeg` and base64.  What OS are you using?  Any extensions installed?

Comment: @Paul Linux/(K)Ubuntu (and TB 24). I do have a few add-ons installed, but I just tested in safe mode and get the same problem. Do you also see the same thing with png (not jpeg)?

Comment: Yep: `Content-Type: image/png;
 name="fbigiaca.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

Comment: @Paul Interesting. At least this suggests it _is_ a problem with (my) Thunderbird then. (Also, it's strange that Gmail via the web is okay with it.)

Comment: Ah, hang on, I did it with TB linux, and got the same as you.

Comment: I guess it is time to search Bugzilla and see if it is reported

Comment: @Paul Oh weird. Thanks for checking. I tried to test on my other laptop running Xubuntu, but I can't even drag and drop into the body :/

Comment: Interesting.  I was doing this in KDE as well - perhaps that is the problem, that KDE doesn't report the mime type of the incoming file correctly...

Comment: @Paul Sorry, perhaps I was being unclear. I couldn't reproduce the bug in Xubuntu, because I couldn't attach inline at all. I did have a look at bugzilla but found nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you were clear, but I am wondering if the problem is KDE rather than thunderbird.  I have enlightment but the file manager isn't working.

Comment: @Paul I just created a new Thunderbird account and email account, and the problem persists (in KDE). I'm currently upgrading my other computer from Xubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, so I'll try that when it's done (probably tomorrow). Unfortunately I don't have Unity or Gnome installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird downloaded from the website works fine, so it looks like it's a bug introduced in the Ubuntu packages. I've filed a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1249940).

To follow up, the Arch packages do *not* contain this bug, it's definitely something introduced in Ubuntu's packaging.